# Find values of $t$ for which a matrix is invertible?

Tags: matrices

$$M = 
\begin{pmatrix}        
2-t & 0 & 0 &  3\\
0  &  t & -t & 0\\
0  & -t & 2t & 0\\
t-2 &  0 &  0 & t+3
\end{pmatrix}$$
Using upper triangular form we have 
$$\det(M)= -t^4 - 4t^3 + 12t^2.$$

Using the determinant, how do I find all values of $t$ for which the matrix is invertible?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $M$ is invertible if and only if $\det(M)\neq 0$.

Now, note that
$$\det(M)= -t^4 - 4t^3 + 12t^2=-t^2(t^2+4t-12)=-t^2(t+6)(t-2).$$

Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Yes, I think I've got the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is not equal to zero. So simply find which values of t that make the determinant zero - and those are the only values that make the matrix not-invertible.

Comment: okay, thank-you very much!